# Can ur-elements be used as/to construct infinitesimals?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, infinitesimals

Background material:

- Truss[[95](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271596/1-s2.0-S0168007200X00164/1-s2.0-016800729400024W/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEC4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIDFt6ZFSvF5VyUcVx2o4MtXDV3jat4z4SqElnmA6CZTwAiBampmDF2VW13bGN%2BKMHZETGORqYFCou9r460VVWHGPQiqzBQg3EAUaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMKtH1uxYiN0pamZazKpAFT4MOVrigR1rUf9%2BLz5tIUA8cVo2KkFywET2M9EIC34wpo0T73eMBWPQT4Jmwl773n%2BTRmDvyD%2FXIteMJBcRRulvzG%2F%2B5uDTd%2Fn7%2B5A0rSLxptOSjrg1VHefVcD82Rcib5sMzAHFAnBP7O%2BEZYESo5wA3dn4DuIFfpxC41GK7eRKX6Sm5ozcyQfADOgjTimWKSlS1Cdn717bH5nlkgwj2PzzZ%2Bj0s%2B5shdwd%2BIaB5lSs7gQSC5%2BtXZKyOPbwFd4h978VLRIASxR%2FNC50w%2F%2BjHbc0bN%2FFbKD1uPPCsW%2FejAHYlnnvInTpb8Txe5uDZQBSdd6lTX3agGKvsJcRH12FsFDbAc%2Bnfrq%2FGyQt6vreSiPHbn2%2FGdiLiUBghMH%2Fc%2FPbge6pQ2R0MuYq55tSzfNsdkBFzpe4oNRqzPoFUGLnKKwegWE75WJp5u28oWTjyn0wOqMrH%2BS6MvT2DarFtlqTpbGWJCi8le9V%2Fd3NwAPeFZ%2B4uB3D5rvrJwHBNrTNPcKbnix2%2BQKwVyxIccgkKvtutG1QaflP0tYiufdcOzSYlmI4HHiGUCyPIKJhPA885oZHst1s8eiVYN3%2Bb4oQkOzB8glagZ1aQO3pjuWKE9smV4udSTMCNx73np6HFKYnSL3ScoTxS8o1zWcvVpaEbl2wZyhUkA4hmjAe7wbvzB4KjaHXTn43KX32TNFVBiLrGUI3zDZqPVRIie4r2nCVolnszslt%2BxTo4EVo57wOS1UqD1b%2Fx92gSCCOT2ORtXekOWmXk5WLwJnct3K0WPCMLHXFuYnWY%2F1l5b8UNtaRXwp9nDiMMkBp4Yd0MKD0hPO52i9t19X6JoeiHxMElC%2BUgN714lg1sGNgocjw77xbUoFn8AAkw5fW9rwY6sgFrql%2FjMdlG8Nxb85%2FB8%2BXq0O%2Bp0TrZYysjTa6QtB%2FnmGsfrg%2B7RRj66sFDTfjw%2BsZLhqyL2RZgFO%2B9iMQtOjeK%2BPRMrBtUCnD%2FIYReF4LIlKTutIlyAzjpWhrL0h%2BxBEsnxot8XB9Z1ththj6b2NIKp6rKJaitRdfrycCoIgVLCwvQC%2BQoz8NoltVZcdMoZvgXDeNtDLt5nNR37mOtQxI7zKNtgYKnUa44hav2bviXH%2B45&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240311T223544Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY42L3JIHS%2F20240311%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=181665374f6919439622c7ff1d358fbb44479162c90cb6f07f02947c0d700d52&hash=6cfc99c58d315630ee10d80f5cc79648cba1993e64284cb1e736321e37a339a6&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=016800729400024W&tid=spdf-bcb97f6f-6ca2-4e21-bea4-03fb92f66ac5&sid=d1a7675b86e23543142b63d5d1076f68de67gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=13165954560750530150&rr=862f04f198e51f29&cc=us)], "The structure of amorphous sets."
- Harrison-Trainor and Kulshreshtha[[22](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.03976.pdf)], "The Logic of Cardinality Comparison Without the Axiom of Choice."
- Halpern and Howard[[74](https://www.academia.edu/21669078/Cardinal_addition_and_the_axiom_of_choice?uc-g-sw=56181418)], "Cardinal addition and the axiom of choice."
- Yao[[23](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.14274.pdf)], "Set Theory With Urelements."

Go to a possible world where:

1. There is (at least) one ur-element $u$.
2. There is an axiom of union such that $\exists \bigcup u$ and, since $u$ is an ur-element, then $\bigcup u = \emptyset$.

*Corollary.* $u \cup \emptyset = \emptyset \cap u = \emptyset$ (also $u \cup u = \emptyset$). Then, if the Cartesian product is a set, let us say that $u \times u = u^2 = \emptyset$, i.e. $u$ appears to be nilpotent. So $u$ is extremely similar to zero, including as nilpotent; these are characteristics of nilpotent infinitesimals; ergo...

Next, consider the problems with an expression like $\frac{\aleph_0}{\aleph_0}$. These are akin to the problems with dividing zero by itself except that the obgenerate resolution set (for the resolution of the expression) of $\frac{0}{0} \rightarrow [0, ?)$ whereas $\frac{\aleph_0}{\aleph_0} \rightarrow [1, \aleph_0]$. Now, if $\frac{1}{0} = \frac{1}{0}$, then $\frac{1}{0} \times 0 = \frac{1}{0} \times \frac{0}{1} = \frac{0}{0}$. So $\frac{1}{0}$ is self-identical dependent on $\frac{0}{0}$ being resolved to 1. By the same reasoning, in order for $\frac{0}{0}$ to be self-identical, though, the expression must be resolved to 0. So if $\frac{1}{0}$ is self-identical, then $\frac{0}{0} = 0 \land \frac{0}{0} = 1$, or then $0 = 1$. But $0 \neq 1$.<sup>**X**</sup> Similarly, $\frac{1}{\aleph_0}$ is self-identical dependent on $\frac{\aleph_0}{\aleph_0} = 1$, but for the self-division of the zeroth aleph to be self-identical, that division must resolve to the zeroth aleph again. So the expression $\frac{1}{\aleph_0}$ is degenerate.<sup>**Y**</sup>

However, go to a possible world with choiceless arithmetic. Then, if I understand the material I am reading, it seems possible that there is some choiceless transfinite $X$ such that $X + X \neq X$ and in particular $\frac{X}{X} = 1$ determinately. From what I have read, it seems possible to have such a choiceless $X$ using ur-elements, as in Fraenkel’s original vision of amorphous sets of ur-elements. Then, still assuming union, we have some e.g. $|\omega_{\alpha} \cup X| = \aleph_{\alpha} + X$. If we fix $X$ as a set of ur-elements, can we define it such that $\frac{1}{\aleph_{\alpha} + X}$ is a regenerate expression? **Can we get both nilpotent and reciprocal-of-infinity infinitesimals from ((co)amorphous sets of) ur-elements?** For example, let $\beth_1$ be the (cardinality of the) alephic continuum and $\mathfrak{B}$ the coalephic one (the one that can exist because of the powerset axiom combined with infinity but in a choiceless world). Are there other ዀ coalephic such that $\frac{1}{\beth_1 + ዀ}$ or $\frac{1}{\mathfrak{B} + ዀ}$ are regenerate infinitesimal expressions? (I assume that since $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}$ regardless of whether an unrestricted choice axiom is in play, then it would not do to claim that $\frac{1}{\beth_1 + \mathfrak{B}}$ is itself regenerate.)

---

<sup>**X**</sup>Or consider that $\frac{3}{2} = 1\frac{1}{2}, \frac{4}{3} = 1\frac{1}{3}$, and so on, so that in general we might say that $\frac{n}{n-1} = 1\frac{1}{n-1}$, except then we get that $\frac{1}{0} = 1\frac{1}{0}$, and a case of $x = x + 1$ seems as objectionable among the rationals as among the integers.

<sup>**Y**</sup>We leave finding the relevant problem with the following expression as an exercise for the interested reader:

$$\sqrt[\aleph_0]{\aleph_0^{\aleph_{\omega}}} = \sqrt[\aleph_0]{\aleph_{\omega}^{\aleph_0}}$$

Comment: I'm not sure the term ‘obgenerate’ is so familiar as to go without remark.  A quick Google only turned it up in [an MSE answer of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809610) to [Trivial vs degenerate cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362194/trivial-vs-degenerate-cases).

Comment: Not to mention coalephic. I suspect this question might need an depth discussion to tease out something a mathematician might be able to answer precisely. I'm not sure MathOverflow is the right place for such a discussion.